# How to properly automount tmpfs inside encrypted home folder on login?

Tags: linux, pam, tmpfs, ecryptfs

I have a user with encrypted home folder which is automounted on login with `pam_ecryptfs` module. I would also like to have several folders automounted as `tmpfs` using *local configuration file* from `luserconf` entry, but it seems that `.pam_mount.conf.xml` is not yet accessible for `pam_mount` at that point. Is there another way to do this?